# Does Spark not support arraylist when writing to elasticsearch?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have the following structure:

```
mylist = [{"key1":"val1"}, {"key2":"val2"}]
myrdd = value_counts.map(lambda item: ('key', { 
    'field': somelist 
}))
```

I get the error:
15/02/10 15:54:08 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 6) on executor ip-10-80-15-145.ec2.internal: org.apache.spark.SparkException (Data of type java.util.ArrayList cannot be used) [duplicate 1]

```
rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile( 
            path='-', 
            outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat", 
            keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
            valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
            conf={ 
        "es.nodes" : "localhost", 
        "es.port" : "9200", 
        "es.resource" : "mboyd/mboydtype" 
    })
```

What I want the document to end up like when written to ES is:

```
{
field:[{"key1":"val1"}, {"key2":"val2"}]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a map instead? it would change your structure slightly though.
    {
      field:{
        "key1": {
          "value":"val1"
...

Comment: I don't want map, I want list!

Comment: I think that you have to give the library the input she needs!!

Comment: @Rolando Please consider accepting an answer if this problem is resolved for you now.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the game, but this is the solution we came up with after running in to this yesterday. Add `'es.input.json': 'true'` to your conf, and then run `json.dumps()` on your data.

Modifying your example, this would look like:

```
import json

rdd = sc.parallelize([{"key1": ["val1", "val2"]}])
json_rdd = rdd.map(json.dumps)
json_rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile( 
    path='-', 
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat", 
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf={ 
        "es.nodes" : "localhost", 
        "es.port" : "9200", 
        "es.resource" : "mboyd/mboydtype",
        "es.input.json": "true"
    }
)
```

Comment: I get the following exception when converting to json: " RDD element of type java.util.HashMap cannot be used" Did you run into this?

Comment: I ran the same code with my conf and ran into the following error - "org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD element of type java.lang.String cannot be used". Is there something I'm doing wrong?
I have my ES on a different server so I'm giving its IP instead of localhost if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem, and the solution passes by converting all lists to tuples .
Converting to json does same.

Comment: is there a way out if i want to keep list as list?

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation on what you mean by "converting to json". Do you mean the same thing as @GBleaney illustrated in his/her answer?

Comment: I have not tested his code, but yes, the same logic as the other answer. 
The main point was not to use tuples but use lists. Since json represents tuples as lists  one could use the other answer, therefore I was validating it also.

Comment: @Karudoso Thanks. Using the other answers and some other blogs I finally made it work. I posted my whole process as another answer to make it easy for future users (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942356/3061686).

Answer (score 3):

I feel there are a few points missing in other answers like you'll have to return a 2-tuple (I don't know why) from your RDD and will also need the Elasticsearch hadoop jar file to make it work. So I'll write the whole process that I had to follow to make it work.

1. Download the Elasticsearch Hadoop jar file. You can download it from the [central maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/) (the latest version should work in most cases - check out their [official requirements README](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop#requirements) for more).
2. Create a file `run.py` with the following minimal code snippet for the demonstration.

   ```
   import json

   import pymongo_spark
   pymongo_spark.activate()

   from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
   conf = SparkConf().setAppName('demo').setMaster('local')
   sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

   rdd = sc.parallelize([{"key1": ["val1", "val2"]}])
   final_rdd = rdd.map(json.dumps).map(lambda x: ('key', x))

   final_rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
       path='-',
       outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
       keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
       valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
       conf={
           "es.nodes" : "<server-ip>",
           "es.port" : "9200",
           "es.resource" : "index_name/doc_type_name",
           "es.input.json": "true"
       }
   )
   ```
3. Run your Spark job with the following command `./bin/spark-submit --jars /path/to/your/jar/file/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.4.jar --driver-class-path /path/to/you/jar/file/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.4.jar --master yarn /path/to/your/run/file/run.py`

HTH!

Comment: Here is a compilation of a few working code snippets which index data into Elasticsearch - https://medium.com/@akkidx/indexing-into-elasticsearch-using-spark-code-snippets-55eabc753272